# Hello. Is it possible to parse data from a single (Tab-separated) file out to different accounts via my xslt

Tags: xml, parsing, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

I am having a bit of a brain lock on the following solution. Currently my xslt and service engine will take a Tab-separated file, break it up to columns and then parse out the data to various public safety agencies via a web service address. The Tab-separated file gets sent from a sever to my watch/folder where the parser and its xslt looks for the pre parsed agency codes and maps it to the final agency code and sends it to the correct agency. But if there are 3 agencies in the same file only the first agency gets sent as the parser consumes and transforms before the other agencies have a chance. Here is an example of my current code.
 I am mapping from column F130, F131 ,F132 and F133. If they are all in the file only F130 gets parsed and the other left out. Wondering if this is even possible to parser out to different accounts. :( Thanks J.

This is the Columns I am trying to parse from a sample file      ^SGB1234^SMD1234^SMN1234^SPS1234^

So when

```
`"substring(/NewDataSet/Row[F1='H']/F130,1,3) = 'SGB'`
```

(I am grabbing the first 3 letters to make as the designator)

Then create a soap event to my API wsdl

```
`<ReportIncident xmlns="http://ee.com">
  <DispatchHeader>
   <AgencyIdentifierCode>
    <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="substring(/NewDataSet/Row[F1='H']/F130,1,3)='SGB'">SG</xsl:when>
   </xsl:choose>
  <AgencyIdentifierCode>`
```

The xml out put for the ReportIncident API

With

`<AgencyIdentifierCode>SG</AgencyIdentifierCode>`

So with all of them I would like to create a ReportIncident push to my API to the different accounts based on the different

`<AgencyIdentifierCode>SG</AgencyIdentifierCode> 
    <AgencyIdentifierCode>SMD</AgencyIdentifierCode> 
    <AgencyIdentifierCode>SNM</AgencyIdentifierCode> 
    <AgencyIdentifierCode>SPS</AgencyIdentifierCode>`

With the code below that I am trying.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ex="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" extension-element-prefixes="ex">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="AgencyIdentifierCode"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <soap:Envelope xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soap:Body>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="substring(/NewDataSet/Row[F1='H']/F130,1,3) = 'SGB' and substring
                (/NewDataSet/Row[F1='H']/F131,1,3) = 'SMD' and substring
                (/NewDataSet/Row[F1='H']/F132,1,3) = 'SNM' and substring
                (/NewDataSet/Row[F1='H']/F133,1,3) = 'SPS'">
                    <ReportIncident xmlns="http://eee.com">
                        <DispatchHeader>
                            <AgencyIdentifierCode>
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="substring(/NewDataSet/Row[F1='H']/F130,1,3)= 'SGB'">SG</xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:when test="substring(/NewDataSet/Row[F1='H']/F131,1,3)= 'SMD'">WA12345</xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:when test="substring(/NewDataSet/Row[F1='H']/F132,1,3)= 'SNM'">BAFD</xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:when test="substring(/NewDataSet/Row[F1='H']/F133,1,3)= 'SPS'">1111</xsl:when>
                                </xsl:choose>
                            </AgencyIdentifierCode>.....................
```

Comment: My first post. So I know its a bit of a novice of a post.

Comment: You should post a **reproducible** code (XML + XSLT) example , along with the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I was able to understand from your question is this: your first condition:

```
<xsl:when test="substring(/NewDataSet/Row[F1='H']/F130,1,3) = 'SGB' 
            and substring(/NewDataSet/Row[F1='H']/F131,1,3) = 'SMD' 
            and substring(/NewDataSet/Row[F1='H']/F132,1,3) = 'SNM' 
            and substring(/NewDataSet/Row[F1='H']/F133,1,3) = 'SPS'">
```

is true only when **all** of the 4 propositions are true. Therefore, if and when you get to the second test:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="substring(/NewDataSet/Row[F1='H']/F130,1,3)= 'SGB'">SG</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="substring(/NewDataSet/Row[F1='H']/F131,1,3)= 'SMD'">WA12345</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="substring(/NewDataSet/Row[F1='H']/F132,1,3)= 'SNM'">BAFD</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="substring(/NewDataSet/Row[F1='H']/F133,1,3)= 'SPS'">1111</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

the result will **always** be "SG" because - as we have just established - the first proposition is true.